# Where is the complete online documentation for the Windows API?

Tags: winapi

It appears that Microsoft is rearranging its web sites again. I'm trying to see the flags available for the `DrawText` function `format` parameter, and the [only page I can find on the Microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtext) says `TBD` where the description should be. I'm hoping that they haven't eliminated this information entirely, it's still essential.

I've noticed a similar trend for other WinAPI functions lately, but this is the first time that vital information was completely missing.

Comment: Good question. I think Microsoft keep hoping everyone will switch to writing Metro apps :)

Comment: Microsoft has been migrating documentation to the new learn.microsoft.com, and recently a lot of the core Windows API docs were switched over in an embarrassingly incomplete and broken state. Use an old link in the [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150815094906/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162498(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @eryksun that's a great suggestion, but I need a way to search wayback as easily as Google searches Microsoft. If you have that it would be worthy of an answer.

Comment: AFAIK, the wayback machine doesn't have a search API to search results for a specific site; just basic keyword searches. Google is aggressive in removing old entries from its database, but DuckDuckGo still returns the old link (for now). However you get the old link (e.g. if you happen to have thousands of MSDN bookmarks...), you can paste it into the wayback machine. You can't use it directly since Microsoft will just redirect it to docs.microsoft.com. Fortunately they're integrating a new feedback system that should actually improve the quality of their documentation... in the long run.

Comment: When you search on Google, its search results show the page title, with the URL underneath it. Towards the right of the URL is a downward pointing arrow. When you click it you get the option to see Google's cached version of the site. Not ideal, but less tedious than going through the wayback machine.

Comment: I remember the golden age - Visual Studio 6 about - when the API was documented in a locally hosted help app with an advanced indexer  and you could construct searches like "DrawText near bold".

Comment: For the last 15 years though, to look up things like flags - I've just resorted to going straight to the header files.

Comment: @chris Really? Usually, the only information there is just a number. I often just google them verbatim.

Comment: The header file would give me the full enumeration, and I could then google "DT_VCENTER" or enums that the relevant API pages would not mention.

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com) still works, at least for some parts (e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms741561(v=vs.85).aspx), although not sure for how long. Its replacement which is WiP (it's a shitty *MS* policy to push it to users' throats in this state) really **sucks**. For your example I couldn't find any reference, only smth related: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6x7y2a4.aspx.

Comment: @IInspectable, this is of no use in this case. Google has already updated their database with redirected URL, `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtext`. This is the incomplete new version, which never should have gone live, and someone should be getting quite an earful for this botched rollout.

Comment: @ChrisBecke It is exactly the same in Visual Studio 2017. Just install autonomous help package.

Comment: @CristiFati, yes, there are still many of the old pages MSDN links that work, but for the affected pages, Microsoft automatically redirects to learn.microsoft.com, e.g. `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162498(v=vs.85).aspx` gets redirected to the new page, which is what the OP needs to avoid.

Comment: @eryksun: When I search for `msdn drawtext` I get the ru-ru version on the first search page. Opening the cached version gets me to [this URL](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:s0QKBMUY-GAJ:https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd162498(v%3Dvs.85).aspx+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=de). That page does not redirect to the new documentation pages. It's the Russian web page, but luckily it hasn't been translated to Russian.

Comment: @IInspectable, for some reason Google has completely removed the en-us version, even though the ru-ru version also redirects to learn.microsoft.com. I don't see why that would be if this is an automated policy. It doesn't seem reliable.

Comment: @VTT, I use the MS help viewer (directly outside of Visual Studio, since I don't use the IDE), but the "Windows Desktop App Development" help doesn't have any archived/legacy functions such as `DrawText`, `EnumFonts`, etc.

Comment: @eryksun: Don't click the URL. Click the *"Cached"* version, as I explained in my [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51315700/where-is-the-complete-online-documentation-for-the-windows-api?noredirect=1#comment89613376_51315700). That chached version does not redirect.

Comment: @IInspectable, I understood that perfectly. If Google still has the URL in its database, then the cached version will still be for that URL, which just happens to be available for the ru-ru page, for *no apparent reason*. If they deleted the en-us URL by policy because of the automatic redirect to learn.microsoft.com, it's not clear why the same wasn't done for the ru-ru URL, which gets redirected as well. As a strategy, I don't want to search for pages in other locales that just happen to have not been deleted for whatever reason. When do I quit looking? Page 2 -- page 200?

Comment: @eryksun: My comment was intended as a workaround, to solve the immediate issue. It is not a long-term solution. The long-term solution is for Microsoft to fix their documentation.

Comment: @eryksun Isn't it just GDI stuff that is missing? It seems that they've messed up a bit because the rest of WinAPI stuff is still there (windows, menus, controls, input, shel, etc). I mean it makes no sense to remove `WM_PAINT` reference while keeping `WM_ERASEBKGND` or removing `DrawText` while keeping `DrawTextWrap` (that is already marked as obsolete).

Comment: @IInspectable, hoping that Google still has an old link in its database for a locale other than en-us which just happens to be in English is not a viable, reliable workaround. But I don't have a functional workaround either when it comes to finding the URL to enter into the Wayback Machine. (Personally, I have thousands of MSDN bookmarks from over the years, so finding the URL isn't a problem for me. And I do already use the offline help viewer as VTT suggested, which has most of what I need except for archived content such as the GDI docs.)

Comment: This question was asked the other day: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51292401/how-to-get-useful-win32-c-api-documentation#comment89565948_51292401